# How to pass Application context on YouTubeThumbnailView to fix Activity has leaked ServiceConnection error

Tags: android, youtube-api

This is a fragment used within a `ViewPager`. It's displaying youtube videos.

But i am getting leaked errors. How to pass Application context on `YouTubeThumbnailView` ?. Some users were able to fix it using this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19812942/1237175. I tried it, but no success...

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements OnCancelListener, YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener{


    ConnectionDetector con;

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    public ViewGroup root;
    private int position;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;
    TopNewsSliderActivity homeActivity;
    WebView webView = null;
    Post data = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_INVITE = 0;
    MoPubView moPubView = null;
    RelativeLayout detailBck = null;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    private boolean canHideStatusBar = false;
    private Dialog errorDialog;

    public static final int REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER = 101;
    private static final int REQ_RESOLVE_SERVICE_MISSING = 2;
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    Activity activity = null;


    public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        DetailFragment f = new DetailFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        homeActivity = (TopNewsSliderActivity) context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_news_details, null);
       con = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());

       sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        detailBck = (RelativeLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.detailBck);

        try{

            data = homeActivity.list_feeds.get(position);
FrameLayout youtubeLayout = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.youtubeLayout);
    ImageView overlayVideoPlay = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.overlayVideoPlay);

    if (!"".equals(data.videoUrl)) {
        overlayVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(homeActivity.getApplicationContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        thumbnailView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        youtubeLayout.addView(thumbnailView,0);

                thumbnailView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
                thumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // Launch standalone YoutTube player
                        Intent intent = null;
                        intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(homeActivity, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, data.videoUrl, 0, true, true);
                        if (intent != null) {
                            if (canResolveIntent(intent)) {
                                canHideStatusBar = true;
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER);
                            } else {
                                // Could not resolve the intent - must need to install or update the YouTube API service.
                                YouTubeInitializationResult
                                        .SERVICE_MISSING
                                        .getErrorDialog(homeActivity, REQ_RESOLVE_SERVICE_MISSING).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }});

            }else{
                overlayVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



            TextView title = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.title);

            title.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("fontSizeSettings", getString(R.string.default_font_size))) + 2);

            TextView newsCategory = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.newsCategory);

            TextView newsPublisher = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.newsPublisher);

            RelativeLayout adContainer = (RelativeLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.adContainer);

            if (!AppConstants.isPurchased){
                if(AppConstants.platform == Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY && moPubView == null){
                    moPubView = new MoPubView(homeActivity);
                    AdManager.showAd(homeActivity, adContainer, moPubView, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    });

                }else if(AppConstants.platform == Platform.AMAZON){
                    homeActivity.showAd(true, adContainer);
                }
            }

            if(homeActivity.tf!=null && !homeActivity.isTamilFontDefault) {
                newsPublisher.setTypeface(homeActivity.tf);
            }

            newsPublisher.setText(data.getPublisher());

            TextView newsColorCode =  (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.newsColor);

            if(data.getCategories()!=null) {
                if(homeActivity.tf!=null && !homeActivity.isTamilFontDefault) {
                    newsCategory.setTypeface(homeActivity.tf);
                }
                newsCategory.setText(data.getCategories());
                newsCategory.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(data.getColor_code()));
                newsColorCode.setText((position + 1) + "");
                LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable) newsColorCode.getBackground();
                final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_id);
                shape.setColor(Color.parseColor(data.getColor_code()));
            }


            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.feedDetail);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
                    webView.setInitialScale(100);
                    //webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3498db")); //  Flicker of colors when the application loads
                    webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    ////webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    //webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    //webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
                    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                    /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                    }*/

                    webView.setScrollContainer(false);
                    webView.setFocusable(false);
                    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

                    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
                        }
                    });
                    webView.setLongClickable(false);
                    webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);

                    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                        @Override
                        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            //forceWebViewRedraw(view);
                        /*  view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var select = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]\r\n" +
                                    "                     if(select)" +
                                    "                       select.style.display = 'block';})()");*/
                            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        }
                    });

                    homeActivity.fetchNewsData(position, data, webView);
            }
        });

                if(homeActivity.tf!=null){
                    title.setTypeface(homeActivity.tf);
                }else {
                    title.setTypeface(null);
                }

            if(homeActivity.pd.getNightMode()==1 || !AppConstants.isDayMode){
                detailBck.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(homeActivity, R.color.black));
                title.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(homeActivity, R.color.white));
            }else {
                detailBck.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(homeActivity, R.color.white));
                title.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(homeActivity, R.color.default_webtext));
            }

                SpannableString spanTitle = new SpannableString(data.getTitle());
                spanTitle.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanTitle.length(), 0);
                title.setText(spanTitle);

            /*ImageView photoView = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

            boolean needReload;
            String image_url = null;
            if (data.getThumbnail()!=null && !data.getThumbnail().equals("")) {
                image_url = data.getThumbnail();
                needReload = true;
                photoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                needReload = false;
                photoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            Log.e("IMAGE-URL->", image_url + "");
            if (needReload) {
                // Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView
                //imageLoader.displayImage(image_url, photoView, options, animateFirstListener);
                homeActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, photoView);
            }*/


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //((ApplicationManager) getActivity().getApplication()).sendGA(nlActivity.t, "GridList Screen");
        return root;
    }

    private boolean canResolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        return resolveInfo != null && !resolveInfo.isEmpty();
    }

    private void forceWebViewRedraw(final WebView webView)
    {
        webView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                webView.invalidate();
                if(!getActivity().isFinishing())
                    webView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {       
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if((isVisible() && isVisibleToUser) && (isResumed() || webView!=null)){
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        ApplicationManager.setCurrentContext(getActivity());
        super.onResume();

         if(data!=null && (!data.getThumbnail().equals("") && data.videoUrl.equals(""))){
            homeActivity.unlockAppBarOpen();
        }else{
            homeActivity.lockAppBarClosed();
        }

        boolean isLandscape = false;
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            isLandscape = true;
        }
        else {
            isLandscape = false;
        }
        if (canHideStatusBar && this.isVisible() && isLandscape) {
            //Utils.hideStatusBar(getActivity());
            canHideStatusBar = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         try {
             if(moPubView!=null){
                 moPubView.setBannerAdListener(null);
                 moPubView.destroy();
                 moPubView = null;
             }
             if (homeActivity.clientXML != null) {
                 homeActivity.clientXML.cancelRequests(homeActivity, true);
                 Log.e("Aync -> OnDestroy ", position + "--> canceled!!!");
                 homeActivity.clientXML = null;
             }
         }catch (Exception e){

         }
            super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 303){
            /*homeActivity.updateSettingsUI();
            homeActivity.refreshListUI();*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {
        thumbnailLoader.setVideo(data.videoUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            if (errorDialog == null || !errorDialog.isShowing()) {
                errorDialog = errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST);
                errorDialog.show();
            }
        } else {
            String errorMessage = "error ";//String.format(getString(R.string.error_thumbnail_view), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error generated:

```
06-16 20:09:40.488 30636-30636/com.androplus.tamilnewsHD E/ActivityThread: Activity com.androplus.activity.TopNewsSliderActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@95bae77 that was originally bound here
                                                                       android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.androplus.activity.TopNewsSliderActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@95bae77 that was originally bound here
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.androplus.fragment.DetailFragment.onCreateView(DetailFragment.java:124)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1520)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:60
```

Comment: did you read `YouTubeThumbnailView` docs? I do not see the code corresponding with **"must"** part of the doc's overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fragment` must be attached to an `Activity` and activity can access the application context from an activity by using [`getapplicationcontext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29). So you need pass the `Activity` (itself) as a parameter to the fragment as one of the constructor parameter. From there you can get the application context as suggested before.

for example :

From your activity if it's called `MainActivity`,

```
Fragment detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(pos, MainActivity.this);
```

then your fragment's `getInstance` will have new parameters as well.

```
public static Fragment newInstance(int position, Activity activity) {
    DetailFragment f = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    this.activity = activity; //getting the activity.
    return f;
}
```

And then you can access the context anywhere as

```
activity.getApplicationContext;
```

Then instead of findViewById you can make a view with app context and add it to its parent view by using something like `parentView.addView(thumbnailView)`,

```
thumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) root.findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview);
```

to

```
thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(activity.getApplicationContext);
// you will have to set attributes dynamically as well, like width and height etc.
```

Comment: So where exactly he has to use application context? `this.activity` in static method?? in which java it works?

Comment: I am getting error near to thumbnailView.initialize(). How to pass application context on this ?

Comment: i have updated. i dont have my machine to write code write now, can you try it?

Comment: Thanks @KushalSharma and selvin !. You both saved my day !. I updated DetailFragment !. You guys can check it out!